# LPAREN Syntax Error in Standard ML

Tags: syntax-error, sml

I'm having a continuous error pop when I try to run this program in ML:

```
fun find(s,file) =
    let fun findHelper(true, true, ch, w, file, acc, acc2) = TextIO.output(TextIO.stdOut, acc2^"\n")
    | findHelper(b1, b2, ch, w, file, acc) = ch = valOf(TextIO.input1(TextIO.file)) acc2^str(ch) 
    if ch = ""  then 
        if w = acc then b1 = true 
        else acc = "" 
    else if ch = "\n" then b2 = true
        else acc^str(ch)


in 
    findHelper(false, false, "", s, file, "", "")
end
```

The error code is:

```
    project.sml:61.3 Error: syntax error: inserting  LPAREN
    project.sml:65.12 Error: syntax error: inserting  RPAREN
```

I've inserted a bunch of parenthesis to no avail and honestly, I don't even know why this error popped. The error is centering around the "if ch = "" then" , but there is no error for the other instance of ch, so I don't know why it error'd one and not the other.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax error is that your inner function contains an expression of the form

```
 A if B then C else D
```

(where A is of the form "x = y"). To sequentially evaluate expressions, you have to use the semicolon operator, and parenthesise, thus:

```
(A; if B then C else D)
```

However, that would only get you past the syntax error, but not help much otherwise. The code doesn't make much sense. You somehow seem to be assuming that you can use `=` to assign to variables -- that is not the case. SML is a functional language, and variables are immutable. What you want to use is recursion.